# How to prevent Theme Resources for Windows Phone

Tags: windows-phone-7, design-patterns, themes, settings, expression-blend

I'm trying to avoid applying WP7's scheme settings to the UI in my application.
What should i do to make my UI elements that are in disabled, accented states are independent from theme switching?

Regards.

Answer (score 2):

Apparently you need to create your own custom theme.

Here is a quote from http://windowsphonegeek.com/articles/Windows-Phone-Mango-Custom-application-Theme-Step-by-Step: 
"Creating a custom application theme is a good solution when you want your application to look in the same way in all themes i.e. to be theme independent. "

Comment: For a pity solution were not found. In-spite of that your link was interesting.